# Two asp projects hosted in one space

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to find the proper way of having two asp projects in one hosting space.

**Project 1** The first project deals with the website front end, shopping cart, and creating orders. It uses EF6 Code First from Database.

**Project 2** The second project is a scaffolding one using EF5, to connect to the backend and display the database entries, and CRUD operations for the manager.

Both of the projects are working fine individually on the local machine. I have also tested them individually on the actual hosting server, and both are working there individually. Both connect to the same database.

**Problem** Now I am wondering how I can deploy these two projects together on the same hosting space. I am not sure what it is called technically, but what I want to achieve is to have the website available for the end users, and the scaffolding be available for the manager. Both the projects are not using any kind of authentication, and I am interested in putting these to work before having an authentication mechanism for only authorised access to the scaffolding part.

Comment: just put them to different folders

Comment: If you are hosting your site to outside world I recommend you implement authentication on your manager application at least otherwise bots will start looking to index your web pages and you will end up exposing management url you don't want others to see unless you provide proper robots.txt file with your site and restrict bots what they can and cannot see.

Comment: @Alex yes that's what I was looking for. Thanks for quick and effective reply.